# Workaround for Compiler Error CS0542: member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I've got a fairly large VB.NET project that was built by a former employee. He got most of it working, but not all of it.

It has been running like this for 2 years, I know. Perhaps 3.

Now, Management is pushing to get this project revived and finish up what was never done.

The project has been assigned to me, and I have been given a month to get up to speed on it.

I am re-writing it in C#, because my coding is stronger in that language.

One of the good ideas he used was to structure the class so that they mimicked the database tables:

- **table name** becomes **class name**
- **column names** become **property names**
- **column datatypes** become **property datatypes**

Here is one small example:

```
Public Class Acct_Code
    Private _Acct_Code_ID As String = String.Empty
    Private _Acct_Code As String = String.Empty

    Public Property Acct_Code_ID() As String
        Get
            Return _Acct_Code_ID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Acct_Code_ID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Acct_Code() As String
        Get
            Return _Acct_Code
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Acct_Code = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Currently, I cannot put this VB code in C# because of [Error CS0542](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdhfk2xk.aspx) that says:

> **Error Message**
>   'user-defined type' : member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
>   A name was used more than once in the same construct. This error might be caused by inadvertently putting a return type on a constructor.

I understand either the class or the property should be renamed; however, I would like to get this project working piece at a time instead of being over here creating code that will not work at all.

### Does anyone know of a way to work around this compiler error - just temporarily until I get the project built?

I know there are ways to ignore warnings and ignore exceptions, but I don't know a way to ignore a compiler error.

Comment: Side note: please conisider to remove unrelated complains about quality of someones code (and probably your personal decision to rewrite production code because you don't like VB.Net) ... Not only it is unrelated to question it shows how your respect others opinions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ignore a violation of the rules of the language. You *must* fix the names.

You may well want to try to fix the names *in VB* before porting, as then you can have a working codebase at all times... which will allow you to take advantage of refactoring. Then when you're sure that all the member names are different from the type names, you can port to C#.

As an aside, when you port that code you should take advantage of automatically implemented properties, leaving:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

(Then try to move away from allowing objects to mutate in all possible ways... that's a different matter :)

Comment: I never even thought about refactoring the VB code. That would do it, too. (FYI: I have already coded in the advantage you mention of auto implemented properties. Much cleaner code!)

Answer (score 3):

To work around the compiler error, just split your class into a base class and a derived class and then move the offending members into the base class.

```
class A
{
    public string B { get; set; } // <-- This compiles just right!
}

class B : A
{
}
```